# Reading data from arduino with nodejs and socketio

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, arduino

I have this simple code that I'm running in arduino

```
char inp;
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  while(Serial.available()>0){
    inp = Serial.read();
    Serial.print(inp);
  }
  Serial.print("--");
  delay(200);
}
```

So it continiously writes "--" and if I send something to arduino it replies with that

Then I have in a js file

```
var strinInfo = "";
tempSerial.on("data", function(data) {
  console.log("data -> " + data);
  if (stringInfo.length < 37){
    stringInfo += data;
  }else{
    io.sockets.emit("message", stringInfo);
    stringInfo = ""
  }
});
```

That sends via sockets what I got from arduino.
My problem is that, for example, if I send

```
"thisisanunusuallongandterriblestringofsymbolsblablablablablablabla"
```

There are missing characters:

```
---------thisisanunusuallongandterribles, 
gofsymbolsblablablablabla--blabla ----, 
-------------------------------------,
```

in this example I'm missing "trin". Is there a way of not losing that characters?

I'm starting with node so my guess is that between the time that it emits the message ... the content from that moment is gone, maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it could be a couple of things.

1. You may be sending data before the listener is ready, the above libs below have that solved.
2. The following line worries me `if (stringInfo.length < 37){`. If you get successive small packets of data, the packet that puts you over 37 will only print the `stringInfo` but will not print the `data` portion.

Libs that connect to Arduino:

- `[Johnny Five][1]`
- `[Firmata][2]`

Both programs interact with Arduinos. Firmata is the low level one with Johnny-Five running on top.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
Actually from arduino I will get always "--" but I'm grouping them in strings of 37 chars (not specific, could be 10 I just want to group them).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it might be the issue of `baud-rate`.

If you are using `serialport` module for serial communication with Arduino than you have to set `serialport baud-rate` to 9600 (same as receiving side i.e. Arduino).

By default serialport baud rate is 115200.